# Can I extend the Angular @Injectable decorator?

Tags: angular

I want to add a custom behavior to all my services that are provided in root when they are initialized. I already have a decorator for this but I would like that it gets applied always when the class is used with the `@Injectable` decorator.

Is this possible? I haven't found any info related and of course I do not want to edit my node modules.

PD: I am using Angular 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically it is possible but I would not recommend it.

1.) Decorators are experimental in TypeScript and you have to configure them in your `tsconfig.json` with the prop `"experimentalDecorators": true`

Quote from the official TypeScript [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html):

> NOTE  Decorators are an experimental feature that may change in future releases.

2.) That's the reason why the Angular team uses so called TypeScript Transformers at compile time to remove them and to be safe if decorators never get away from the 'experimental' status or worse are removed. TypeScript Transformers give you the possibility to change the AST (Abstract Syntax Tree) of your written source at compile time.
[Here](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/do-you-know-how-angular-transforms-your-code-7943b9d32829) is a very good overview over these built-in transformers.

Of course you can build your "custom" TypeScript transformer, but I would not recommend it because it is a lot of trial and error involved. But there are blogposts out there. I will not link them ;)

3.) [Maxim did write a custom](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/implementing-custom-component-decorator-in-angular-4d037d5a3f0d) `@Component` decorator once but I think it will not suffice your needs.

**Summary**

So all in all my proposed solution would be either:

- Pull that logic in a independent service and inject it in the given services
- Using class inheritance and/or abstract classes if you want to share methods.
- ... I would favor composition over inheritance though
- Initializing these services within their service constructor if needed (bad practice to have logic in the constructor, though I would go for it anytime if it's solving my problems)
- Injection the services in the constructor of the NgModule and initialize them

... if all these approaches are not possible I would start, thinking about a custom decorator. Hiding additional magic behind a given decorator is not desirable, because nobody would expect it there and this is calling for troubles. But that's just my opinion. As pointed out above: Even a custom decorator would be built upon experimental features unless you write a transformer. So if I'd had the choice to avoid them I would go for it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your complete answer. The decorator I want is for simple Debugging help. It stores a reference of  my service in the window object using a prefix and the service name, just when I am on a non production environment. So technically if it breaks I would not be so terrible...